# Differences between VS2010's std::shared_ptr and boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, shared-ptr

What are the differences between VS2010's `std::shared_ptr` and `boost::shared_ptr`?

Are the implementations almost the same? Or are there significant differences?

What is the most efficient/optimized?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not have a look at the source code?

Comment: There are differences. How do we know if they are significant for you?

Comment: @Nick: In general, Boost and STL C++ source codes are not trivial to read (sometimes they are [read-only/write-only code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2011/09/27/read-only-and-write-only-computer-languages.aspx)). I'm considering them more like black-boxes.

Comment: @BoPersson: if there are known differences, it would be interesting to read about them. e.g. Boost's one is better for space efficiency, VS2010's one is better for speed, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS2010's `shared_ptr` is implementation conforming (or, at least, trying to conform) C++11 standard.

`boost::shared_ptr` on the other hand, was developed way earlier, and as part of boost rather than C++ standard library. I believe both are efficient enough for production use, but using boost forces you to... use boost ;). Which in some cases is quite unacceptable.

Comment: using Boost is not a problem (there are other Boost libraries that can come in handy and are not present in VS2010 std::). And AFAIK it is possible to use Boost in commercial products (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: FWIW, in VS2008 tr1::shared_ptr implementation was buggy (although it seems that in VS2010 they fixed this particular bug):
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/488804/tr1-shared-ptr-reset-causes-crash

Comment: It is possible to use it in commercial products, but some companies (i believe even google[citation needed]) have strong code policy against boost and other libraries.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Yes, you are right, Google does not support all `boost` collections, but only the ones they have approved. `boost:array`, `boost:ptr_container` are allowed at Google. Google Style Guide: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Boost